# Replace continuous occurrence of "\n" with a single "\n" in python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, newline

I have a text file that contains multiple blank lines and I want to remove those blank lines.
The only solution I can come up with is to remove the occurrence of "\n"s with a single "\n". I know this can be done using a regular expression but don't know how to do it in python. I googled a lot and it didn't work.

Comment: *What* didn't work? Can you show us what you tried? Can you give us sample input and expected output? Try to include example lines that should *not* be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re
txt = re.sub('\n+','\n',txt)
```

Substitute any sequence of 1 or more new-lines with a single new-line.

Comment: Thanks. That was a quick answer and worked. Accepting in 5 mins :D

Comment: Are you sure that you don't need to use a raw string: `re.sub(r'\n{2,}', r'\n', txt)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Not necessary in this case, since `\n` is a new line in normal strings.

Comment: @khelwood As would be done in the case of accepting one occurrence but not two or more than two, this expression does not work: re.sub(r'\n{2,}', r'\n', txt)

Comment: @user140259 I don't understand what your comment is supposed to mean.

Comment: @khelwood I meant to replace: "\n\n" -> " ", BUT not one occurrence: "\n"